# Beautiful Soup: how to tell when recursive parsing of html is nested

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have some html that I am using BeautifulSoup to parse.  I am using the following code to get all the categories out of the dom:

```
def dataList(element):
    categoryList = []
    try:
        for ul in categorySoup('ul', recursive=False):
            for li in ul('li', recursive=True):
                categoryList.append(li.a.contents)


        return categoryList
    except:
        return ['broken!']
```

The problem I am having is with this code I can't tell what is nested within what.  Is there a way that I can add append an item to categoryList any time that I go in or out of a li/ul so I can see what the hierarchy of the data is?
A basic/simplified example of what the html looks like is this:

```
<ul>
  <li>category1
    <ul>
      <li>subcategory1
        <ul>
          <li>subsubcategory1</li>
          <li>subsubcategory2</li>
        </ul>
      <li>subcategory2</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  <li>categorya
    <ul>
      <li>subcategorya</li>
      <li>subcategoryb
        <ul>
          <li>subsubcategorya</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

An actual example of what I am giving it is this:

```
<li><b><a href="/getcats/fullcategorytree.php?RootID=20081#20081" name="20081">Antiques</a></b> #20081<ul>\n<li><b><a href="/products.php?extra=Antiquities&amp;cat=37903&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Antiquities</a> #37903</b>\n<ul>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Byzantine&amp;cat=162922&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Byzantine</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162922 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Celtic&amp;cat=162923&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Celtic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162923 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Egyptian&amp;cat=37905&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Egyptian</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #37905 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Far+Eastern&amp;cat=162916&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Far Eastern</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162916 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Greek&amp;cat=37906&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Greek</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #37906 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Holy+Land&amp;cat=162917&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Holy Land</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162917 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Islamic&amp;cat=162918&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Islamic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162918 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Near+Eastern&amp;cat=91101&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Near Eastern</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #91101 (leaf)</img></li>\n<li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Neolithic+%26+Paleolithic&amp;cat=66834&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Neolithic &amp; Paleolithic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #66834 (leaf)</img></li>
```

They can go a lot more deep then 2 or 3 levels though.  Here is the actual source we are trying to parse from:http://www.isoldwhat.com/getcats/fullcategorytree.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do a recursive function to search (and store in a `dict`) for listings and append the current `ul` node into the last found `li`.

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """
<ul><li><b><a href="/getcats/fullcategorytree.php?RootID=20081#20081" name="20081">Antiques</a></b> #20081
<ul>\n
    <li><b><a href="/products.php?extra=Antiquities&amp;cat=37903&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Antiquities</a> #37903</b>\n
        <ul>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Byzantine&amp;cat=162922&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Byzantine</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162922 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Celtic&amp;cat=162923&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Celtic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162923 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Egyptian&amp;cat=37905&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Egyptian</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #37905 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Far+Eastern&amp;cat=162916&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Far Eastern</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162916 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Greek&amp;cat=37906&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Greek</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #37906 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Holy+Land&amp;cat=162917&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Holy Land</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162917 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Islamic&amp;cat=162918&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Islamic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #162918 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Near+Eastern&amp;cat=91101&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Near Eastern</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #91101 (leaf)</img>
            </li>\n
            <li><a class="elink" href="/products.php?extra=Neolithic+%26+Paleolithic&amp;cat=66834&amp;keywords=" rel="nofollow">Neolithic &amp; Paleolithic</a>\xa0 <img alt="Go to eBay" height="9" src="/images/graphics/smallebay.gif" style="display:inline;" width="16"> #66834 (leaf)</img>
            </li></ul>"""

def Tree(ul):
    result = {}
    for li in ul.find_all("li", recursive=False):
        key = next(li.stripped_strings)
        HasUL = li.find("ul")
        #If you want only the node text
        result[key] = None if HasUL is None else Tree(HasUL)
        #If the li have a `a` tag and you want the url
        #result["%s - %s" % (key, li.find("a")["href"])] = None if HasUL is None else Tree(HasUL)
    return result

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

print (Tree(soup.find("ul")))
```

The second method outputs:

```
{'Antiques - /getcats/fullcategorytree.php?RootID=20081#20081': {'Antiquities - /products.php?extra=Antiquities&cat=37903&keywords=': {'Byzantine - /products.php?extra=Byzantine&cat=162922&keywords=': None, 'Celtic - /products.php?extra=Celtic&cat=162923&keywords=': None, 'Egyptian - /products.php?extra=Egyptian&cat=37905&keywords=': None, 'Far Eastern - /products.php?extra=Far+Eastern&cat=162916&keywords=': None, 'Greek - /products.php?extra=Greek&cat=37906&keywords=': None, 'Holy Land - /products.php?extra=Holy+Land&cat=162917&keywords=': None, 'Islamic - /products.php?extra=Islamic&cat=162918&keywords=': None, 'Near Eastern - /products.php?extra=Near+Eastern&cat=91101&keywords=': None, 'Neolithic & Paleolithic - /products.php?extra=Neolithic+%26+Paleolithic&cat=66834&keywords=': None}}}
```